# Parallel method to get all the eigenvalues of a large sparse matrix

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, sparse-matrix, hpc, eigenvalue

1. Is it possible to compute **all** the **eigenvalues** of a large **sparse** matrix **using multiple CPUs** ?
2. If yes, then is it possible to do it **without storing the full dense matrix** in memory ? (using only the stored sparse matrix)
3. If yes, then what's a good (**rapid** and **low memory usage**) method to do it ?
4. Can `numpy` or `scipy` do it ?

My matrix is **complex**, **non-hermitian**, as **sparse** as the identity matrix  and of dimension `N x N` where `N = BinomialCoefficient(L,Floor(L/2))` where we need to take **`L`** **as large as possible**.

For example, with `L = 20`, `N = 184 756` it is 99.9995% sparse, having just `N` non-zero elements. So, the memory usage of the sparse matrix is ~0.1GB but would be ~10TB for the dense matrix.
With `L = 30`, `N = 155 117 520` and we use ~60GB (sparse) and ~10EB (dense). So it's impraticable to store the full dense matrix in memory.

I have access to Intel® Gold 6148 Skylake @ 2.4 [GHz] CPUs with up to 752 [GB] of RAM each. I could use Python, C (ScaLAPACK, OpenBLAS, MAGMA, ELPA, MUMPS, SuperLU, SuiteSparse, PETSc, Lis,...), C++ (Armadillo, Eigen, BLitz++, Trilinos,...), Matlab, R, Perl, Fortran, mpi4py, CUDA, Intel® Math Kernel Library, and a few other softwares.

I build my matrix using Python (`scipy.sparse`, `numpy` and `multiprocessing`). I've tried using `numpy.linalg.eigvals()` and `scipy.linalg.eigvals()`, but it seems that they only use the cores of one CPU. I could look further into those, but I wont if there's a better way to solve my matrix.

For the curious ones, my matrix comes from a representation of a non-hermitian operator on a subset of states of a length `L` quantum spin 1/2 chain with strong interactions. I need the full spectrum because it allows me to study the level spacing distribution of the energy spectrum for a fixed set of quantum numbers.

I'm far from being a professional in computer science, so if I missed some basic concept please be clement.

Comment: Would you mind, @Gab to add a few details - ***a)*** What are your current, as-is processing-times? ***b)*** How often do you experience solution-instabilities? ***c)*** What are your (im-)precision tresholds for the solution of eigenvalues? ***d)*** How large **L**-s are your final solution aiming at? ***e)*** What are your domain-of-expertise acceptable **processing-times** for computing that sized eigenvalue problems? ***f)*** What are your **time**-to-market expectations for having such final solution RTO? ***g)*** What are your **financing** restrictions for achieving all those above met?

Comment: Did you consider https://spectralib.org/ ?

Comment: a) I achieved L=17 with a less powerful build (CPU and RAM) in around 4h  b) From L=4 to 17 I did not experience any solution-instabilities  c) As I'm studying the spacing between eigenvalues, precision is important; I was aiming for something around 10^(-10) (my eigenvalues are around [0,40])  d) I'd like to reach at least L=22, but the more the better  e) I'd say 20h f) I don't understand the question, I'm sorry  g) I should do it with already available resources only.

Comment: No, I did not know about spectralib, but I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: @Gab thx for the as-is state details. The point about precision is cardinal, standard tools have problems with both IEEE-floating points number representation precision & solver method's instabilities(more often iterative methods). For small L-s, in-cache computing gets fast on i-Gold-6148 (having above 27+ MB L3-cache,data-access keeps to happen at costs of units of **[ns]**) **L ~30+** gets you above **5 [GB]** of data representing the sparse-NxN matrix of complex values.This turns the processing from CPU-intensive (happily in-cache) into RAM-I/O intensive… **2+ orders of magnitude slower**

Comment: + Not all solvers are ready to meet all of your requirements, those that can handle **sparse**-representations of matrix data need not be also ready for **complex** data-type,some can handle both,but only for symmetric or multi-band layouts,so you will spend lot of time to check the packages readiness for the particular use-case you need: **efficient** (in both TimeDOMAIN =fast & SpaceDOMAIN =low RAM or efficiently cluster-distributed sparse-representation of data) for **large** (costs of scaling go strongly against you ~ orders of magnitude slower for Out-of-Cache, the more for distributed )

Comment: @Gab ( you may already be aware, that comments, that do not start with @-nickame do not get notified to other StackOverflow users, so making a comment for OneLyner will need to mention the @-OneLyner otherwise she/he will not get a notification about your comment for her/him )

Comment: @user3666197 Thanks for all the info! So for the first question "Is it possible to compute all the eigenvalues of a large sparse matrix using multiple CPUs ?", the answer would be yes ? I've edited the question to try to make it simpler and clearer.

Comment: @OneLyner It seems like Spectralib doesn't support complex type matrices.

Comment: @Gab oups sorry, I missed that point :)

Comment: @Gab just tired scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs (based on https://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/ it seems) on my machine and it's is using multiple CPUs, but not all of them all the time. Part of the computation uses only one, part of the computation go up to 8.

Comment: @OneLyner Did you try to get all the eigenvalues with it? Because it can only get up to N-2 eigenvalues and behaves very badly (way worst than dense methods) when trying to get this many eigenvalues. (By default it computes only 6 eigenvalues)